# Gallery Next Photo script

Tags: php

I have a gallery page and I need this link:

`echo '<a href="index.php?action=vg&limit='.$limit, $plusOne .'">Next</a>';`

to take me to the next page when I click it. The `$limit` variable is set in the url with `&limit=<number goes here>` and `$plusOne` is set in the script with the value of `+ 1`

When the link is clicked it simply ass a "1" to the link. So it would be http://www.examplesite.com/index.php?action=vg&limit=11 instead of just making limit 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with simple mathoperators:

```
echo '<a href="index.php?action=vg&limit='.($limit + 1).'">Next</a>';
```